# I keep getting errors while trying to change a view's dimensions with LayoutParams

Tags: java, android

I have an activity set up like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Button>
    <LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>
             <LinearLayout>  <--- THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO CHANGE
        <RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to change that linear layout's height, so I tried using LayoutParams, and it always throws me an error during runtime. What am I doing wrong? Here's my attempt at LayoutParams:

```
    LinearLayout g1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
g1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 30));
```

UPDATE: 
Here's the XML file in question, what I am interested in changing is graph1 graph2 graph3 and graph4.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#16467A"
    android:padding="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
            android:layout_width="205dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/liniar"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/kvadrat"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="ОК"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/liniar"
            android:layout_width="205dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_ok"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
            android:background="@drawable/kvadrat"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="204dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/graph1"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="#00a313"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/graph2"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/graph1"
                    android:background="#00a313"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/graph3"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/graph2"
                    android:background="#00a313"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/graph4"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/graph3"
                    android:background="#00a313"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
                android:text="A"
                android:textColor="#DCA601"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
                android:text="B"
                android:textColor="#DCA601"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:text="C"
                android:textColor="#DCA601"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:text="D"
                android:textColor="#DCA601"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your error. If you cannot interpret what the stack trace is telling you, paste in the stack trace when you ask questions.

However, your problem would appear to be that you are are trying to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` for a child of a `RelativeLayout`, so my guess is that you are getting a `ClassCastException`.

The specific flavor of `LayoutParams` is determined by the *parent* of the `View`, not the `View` itself.

BTW, you might consider calling `getLayoutParams()`, adjusting the existing instance, and updating it via `setLayoutParams()`, rather than creating a new instance. Particularly with savvy use of base classes (e.g., `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, the base class for both `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`), you can better insulate yourself from the specific class of the parent.

Comment: Yeah, I tried a bunch of things including what you said, but none worked...

This line of code is exactly what you suggest, but it still gives me errors:

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) g1.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 30;
g1.setLayoutParams(params);`

Comment: @DavidSimka: Without knowing what the error is (e.g., by editing your question to have your current code and the stack trace), it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: @DavidSimka: Yes, though it is usually simpler just to highlight the lines in LogCat, press `<Ctrl>-<C>`, then paste them into the question (formatted as source). Your error has nothing to do with the code in your question -- you have a `NullPointerException` on line 52 of `MainActivity.java`, in an `onClick()` method.

Comment: It's actually line 525 which is:
g1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));

so yeah, it's a null pointer exception in the LayoutParams line of code that I've been trying to add...

Comment: @DavidSimka: Sorry about misreading the line number. Then `g1` is `null`. Either the ID is not `graph1`, or your code and resources are slightly out of sync in the build process (do Project > Clean from the Eclipse main menu to fix this), or you have not loaded `graph1` into the activity's content yet.

Comment: Still no progress...

I have updated the main post with the XML, maybe there is the problem. Could you tell me exactly how you think I should go about changing the views' dimentions (mainly height) from java?

Comment: @DavidSimka: AFAICT, your problem isn't with "changing the views' dimentions (mainly height) from java". That being said, I would suggest perhaps rethinking your approach, because dynamic sizing like this is a code smell, suggesting that you should be doing something else (e.g., using `layout_weight`, or writing a custom `ViewGroup` that can handle your business rules). Tactically, make sure you are not executing your size-changing code until after you have loaded the above XML into the activity (e.g., `setContentView()`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the LayoutParams of the parent, so you need to use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, since the linear layout is in a relative layout.

Comment: yeaah, it still gives me error when I do it liek this:

g1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: Try RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

Also add the logcat stack trace and your actual layout.xml file.

Comment: g1 is null, you probably have not looked it up, or it was not able to find the view in the layout you inflated.